# Applying XSL to XML with PowerShell : Exception calling "Transform"

Tags: xml, powershell, xslt

I'm trying to clean XML Files with an XSL Transformation. When I'm applying my XSL directly to my XML File, it works fine. But now I want to clean every XML File I have in a directory. I've tried to create a PowerShell script, to load and transform XML Files.

Here is my code :

```
$dir = "C:\MyDirectory"
$XSLFileName = "XSLTFile.xsl"
$XSLFileInput = $dir + $XSLFileName

$XMLFileName = "Input.xml"
$XMLInputFile = $dir + $XMLFileName
$OutputFileName = "Output.xml"
$XMLOutputFile = $dir + $OutputFileName

cd $dir 

$XSLInputElement = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform;
$XSLInputElement.Load($XSLFileInput)

$XMLInputDoc = Get-Content -Path $XMLInputFile

$reader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($XMLInputFile)
$writer = [System.Xml.XmlTextWriter]::Create($XMLOutputFile)

$XSLInputElement.Transform($XMLInputDoc, $writer)
```

I've been threw some docs and SO subjects to find how to use the `Transform()` method, but I haven't found how to deal with this error :

```
Exception calling "Transform" with "2" argument(s): "Caractères non conformes dans le chemin d'accès."
At C:\ScirptsDirs\StackOverFlowTransformExample.ps1:20 char:1
+ $XSLInputElement.Transform($XMLInputDoc, $writter)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException
```

> Note : "Caractères non conformes dans le chemin d'accès." means :
> Invalid symbol found in the access path.

What I want to do is to clean my XML File, and to create an other XML File but with the XSL Transformation applied to it.

**EDIT :** I've also tried this way, as Martin said :

```
$XSLInputElement.Transform($XMLInputFile, $XMLOutputFile)
```

But this time, I have thee following error :

```
Exception calling "Transform" with "2" argument(s): "Execution of the 'document()' function was prohibited. Use the XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction property to enable it. An error occurred at  D:\MyDirectory\XSLTFile.xsl(220,3)."
At C:\ScirptsDirs\StackOverFlowTransformExample.ps1:20 char:1
+ $XSLInputElement.Transform($XMLInputFile, $XMLOutputFile)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : XslTransformException
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the input and output file name respectively path as a string then simply use `$XSLInputElement.Transform($XMLInputFile, $XMLOutputFile)`.

Comment: Thanks Martin, but it's not working, i've tried this way, and I have an other error. I've edited my question so that you will be able to see the other error raised when I try your with your method.

Comment: Well, that error suggests that the `Transform` call with the arguments as suggested is working, only that the XSLT stylesheet you use calls the `document` function, so that you first need to make sure you use `$XsltSettings = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltSettings(true, false);` and `$XSLInputElement = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform; $XSLInputElement.Load($XSLFileInput, $XsltSettings, New-Object System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver);`

Comment: The right Powershell syntax to create boolean parameters seems to be `$XsltSettings = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltSettings($true, $false);`

Comment: I've done it this way :

`$XsltSettings = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltSettings
$XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction = 1`

Answer (score 3):

This is working for me. The extra lines are for enabling scripts in the xsl.

EDIT. Seems the solution to above was that a line to enable the document function was needed. Similar to how I enable scripts.

```
$xslt_settings.EnableDocumentFunction = 1;
```

could be added to my function

```
function TransformXML{
    param ($xml, $xsl, $output)

    if (-not $xml -or -not $xsl -or -not $output)
    {
        Write-Host "& .\xslt.ps1 [-xml] xml-input [-xsl] xsl-input [-output] transform-output"
        return 0;
    }

    Try
    {
        $xslt_settings = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltSettings;
        $XmlUrlResolver = New-Object System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver;
        $xslt_settings.EnableScript = 1;

        $xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform;
        $xslt.Load($xsl,$xslt_settings,$XmlUrlResolver);
        $xslt.Transform($xml, $output);

    }

    Catch
    {
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
        Write-Host  'Error'$ErrorMessage':'$FailedItem':' $_.Exception;
        return 0
    }
    return 1

}
```

Comment: This solution worked great for me.  One small correction is the initial return 0 statement has a typoe.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the typo (finally)

Comment: after re-reading and this time understanding the comments to the accepted answer the original poster needed
$xslt_settings.EnableDocumentFunction = 1;

While my problem was that I was using a vbs script in the xsl and needed
$xslt_settings.EnableScript = 1;

Generally the problem in both cases was lack of  understanding of the XsltSettings object.