# How to convert property in XML with powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, format

I try to convert xml from this:

```
<test>
    <sub ID="126754">
        <name>test</name>
    </sub>
    <sub ID="126769">
        <name>test2</name>
    </sub>
</test>
```

to this :

```
<test>
    <sub>
        <ID>126754</ID>
        <name>test</name>
    </sub>
    <sub>
        <ID>126769</ID>
        <name>test2</name>
    </sub>
</test>
```

I can read and loop in my file but I don't find how to convert `ID=nnnnnn` to `<ID>nnnnnn</ID>`

Comment: This can be accomplished with XSLT.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645359/convert-xml-attributes-to-elements-xslt) for an example style sheet transform that changes attributes into elements, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024568/applying-xsl-to-xml-with-powershell-exception-calling-transform) for an example of using PowerShell to apply a style sheet.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```
$newContent = @()
$test=gc C:\temp\xmll.xml

ForEach($Regel In $Text) {
  if($Regel -match "ID=\d{6}") {
    $newContent += "    <sub>"
    $newContent += "        <ID>$($Regel.Substring(8, 10))</ID>"

  } else {
    $newContent += $Regel
  }
}

$newContent
```